# Refresh an opened form vb.net

Tags: vb.net, forms, refresh

I have my form 1 and when I click in a button it opens my form 2. I want to introduce some information in this second form in order to uptade the first form.
I tried this:

```
Public class Form2

    Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click

    ... {some code here}

    Form1.Refresh()
    Me.Close()

    End Sub
End Class
```

But this isn't refreshing my form1. I know I can close the first form and open it again, but i don't pretend that.
Is there any other way to do this?

Comment: What exactly do you think that `Refresh` method does?  It's not going to magically know to get data from a database or from a file or whatever else.  Perhaps you should explain what `Form2` actually does and what exactly you expect to happen in `Form1`.  My guess is that you have data in a grid in `Form1` and you making changes to the database in `Form2` and expecting `Form1` to reflect those changes. I say that because it's common that beginners do that when it's completely wrong. In that case, you should be making the changes in `Form1` first, then saving them to the database from there.

Comment: @jmcilhinney hello. Yap but I pretend that. I want to "run" the code of first form after making somes changes in the second form.

Comment: If you want to execute some code then you need to execute that code.  Calling `Refresh` is not going to do that and you should not simply assume that it will.

Comment: @jmcilhinney yes but how can I execute it from another form?

Comment: How do you usually execute code in an object?  You call a method..  It has to be a method that actually contains the code you want executed though.  Refresh doesn't contain such code so it won't magically execute such code.

Answer (score -1):

Based on the input provided by you, you should fetch the data again from the database in the first form. The refresh method / event handler is different that the Form Load method. You need to call again the method / code responsible for fetching the data from the database.

Comment: An answer MUST contain a solution to the question as asked.  If you want to clarify the question then add a comment to the question.

Comment: @andreas charidemou hello. Yes, some data is being saved. Then, I want to refresh first form so it can check the new information in database.

Comment: Do you call again the method which is responsible for fetching the data from the database? The refresh method / event handler is different that the Form Load method. You need to call again the method / code responsible for fetching the data from the database.

Comment: @jmcilhinney I don't have yet privilege to add a comment unless I add an answer. I don't know if this is a bug but I tried to add a comment in the first place and did not allowed it to me.

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer.

Comment: An answer MUST contain an answer. If you can't post a comment then don't post anything.

Comment: Just wanted to help

Comment: Helping is good, but don't break the rules of the site to do so.

Comment: Ok my friend. Sorry